# Are all the strings from a program (in .java) stored in RAM when it's launched (Android)?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a game on Android similar to Who wants to be a millionaire, and I'm wondering what s the best way to store the questions and answers. I want to have at least a 300-400 questions to start with and add about 100 every update. Right now I have them stored in a static class like this:

```
public class Qs {
public static Question questions[][];
public static Question q1e1,q1e2,q1e3,q2e1,q2e2,q2e3,q3e1,q3e2,q3e3,q4e1,q4e2,q4e3;

public static void load(){



    q1e1 =  new Question("Question","Answer","wrong answer","wrong answer","wrong answer");
    q1e2 =  new Question("Question","Answer","wrong answer","wrong answer","wrong answer");
    q1e3 =  new Question("Question","Answer","wrong answer","wrong answer","wrong answer");


    Question level1[] = new Question[]{q1e1,q1e2,q1e3};
    Question level2[] = new Question[]{q2e1,q2e2,q2e3};
    Question level3[] = new Question[]{q3e1,q3e2,q3e3};
    Question level4[] = new Question[]{q4e1,q4e2,q4e3};

    questions = new Question[][]{level1,level2,level3,level4};

}
```

}

But I really don't know what will this do when I have hundreds of questions in that clas. Will they all load into memory and probably slow the phone down a lot ? For editing and adding questions it's fine, no need for fancy xml or anything, I'm just concerned about slowing down the phone (otherwise my app is really not demanding). Thanks for any answers, comments and tips!

Comment: Using databases is a classic way of solving problems with storing a huge amount of data.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I will try to implement the SQL, though I have no experience with it. Thanks for such quick response(s)!

Comment: It'll be easy.  From a quick glance it looks like you'll need the following fields: a primary ID of some kind, question, answer, wrong1, wrong2, wrong3, and level.   Then use a random number generator to pick the ids of 3 randomly of the same level, load their data, and go.  alternatively and less-RDB-inclined would be to have 4 tables, 1 for each level of question, it will make randomly grabbing them easier but more awkward to maintain  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use classes for logic, not storage. You can either use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) (doesn't fit well) or [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) (It is meant for such usage).

Comment: @Randalfien - BTW, if you want to save some data structures to a file as text, you don't have to use XML, you can use JSON which is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You can go with [Sqlite as a persistence store](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) and take a little piece out in the memory when needed.

Comment: Yep, and android has great native support for SQLite. Also, I should mention that a couple hundred strings held in memory isn't going to break any modern device. Its what, maybe 8kb?  But it is best practice to only init what you are using, so to SQL you go! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an external storage for this.

This will make you application smaller. This will also ease the maintenance and allow you maintaining the questionnaire outside the app: a new version of the questionnaire will not lead you to recompile and republish the app (you can make your app to download new versions of the questionnaire from time to time, but this is another topic).

At first glance I see two valid options:

- SQLite (lightweight database embedded in Android)
- Android external storage (file system that allows you storing XMLs, or keys/values text files, or any other format)

There is an interesting post about that on the Android blog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html